# how to add a new GitHub file to your project with git codes

Tags: git, github

I committed a repository, then I understood forgot Readme file, so I added it from GitHub website.

now my repository has one file more than my local files (Readme file), how can I add readme file to my local files without downloading, I mean just with Git codes???
something like:
git clone ...

I need to know this because I want to learn how push and pull, and clone exactly work (if these related).

Comment: use `git pull` to get the latest changes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+update+local+repository

Answer (score 1):

```
git pull origin main
```

Is a combination of `git fetch` and `git merge`

This updates your local repository with the files from your remote repository

Note that you need to have origin set to your github repository.
eg. [https://github.com/[Your_github_profile]/[repo_name].git](https://github.com/%5BYour_github_profile%5D/%5Brepo_name%5D.git)

'main' can also vary depending on how you named your branch,
another common name is 'master'

```
git clone https://github.com/[your_profile]/[repo_name].git
```

This is how to get a local copy of an existing repository, usually only executed once, after that you use `git pull origin main` to update

Answer (score 0):

Maybe will help.

Open a terminal from the root directory of your local repository. Run the following command to fetch the latest changes from the remote repository:

```
git fetch (your origin)
```

When the fetch is complete, you can checkout the readme file to your local repository using the following command:
`git checkout (origin and next address to readme) -- readme._` (txt, md or any type you use)